# helm/kubectl - Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout

Tags: ssl, kubernetes-helm, kubectl, minikube

I've been using Kubernetes/helm - connecting to GCP from local machine w/o any issue, however - today when i started to work using Minikube, it is giving me connectivity error(intermittently) with both helm & kubectl

```
Karans-MacBook-Pro:bitnami-tomcat karanalang$ kubectl describe service/tomcat
Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout


Karans-MacBook-Pro:bitnami-tomcat karanalang$ helm list
Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get "https://127.0.0.1:49522/version?timeout=32s": net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

how do i debug/fix this ?

tia!

Comment: check this https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3106#issuecomment-461113410

Comment: thnx, will check and update !